# How to display sunrise and sunset time in the local time of the city that is being searched

Tags: javascript, weather-api

I have created a project that displays the sunrise and sunset by searching the name of the city. I use the open weather API.

However, when I search for a city with different timezone than my country (Greece), it converts the sunrise-sunset times to Greece's local timezone.

For example, I search "Albania"

[image]

The sunrise and sunset times in Albania are displayed in Greece's timezone.
(Note: Greece is 1 hour ahead of Albania)

[image]

Normally, the sunrise-sunset times in Albania are: 7:02 AM and 4:35 PM.

However, it displays 8:02 and 17:35 which are 1 hour ahead of the normal sunrise-sunset times because they are converted to Greece's local timezone.

**MY CODE**

```js
let weather = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  fetchWeather: function (city) {
    fetch(
      "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
        city +
        "&units=metric&lang=en&appid=" +
        this.apiKey
    )
  
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          alert("No weather found.");
          throw new Error("No weather found.");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => this.displayWeather(data));
  },
  
  //fetching the API parameters:
  displayWeather: function (data) {
    const { name } = data;
    const { sunrise } = data.sys;
    const { sunset } = data.sys;

  
//Displaying the results:
    document.querySelector(".city").innerText = "Weather: " + name;
    document.querySelector(".sunrise").innerText = "Sunrise: " + window.moment(sunrise * 1000).format('HH:mm a');
    document.querySelector(".sunset").innerText = "Sunset: " + window.moment(sunset * 1000).format('HH:mm a');
    document.querySelector(".weather").classList.remove("loading");
    document.body.style.backgroundImage =
      "url('https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?')"; 
  },

  
  search: function () {
    this.fetchWeather(document.querySelector(".search-bar").value);
  },
};

document.querySelector(".search button").addEventListener("click", function () {
  weather.search();
});

document
  .querySelector(".search-bar")
  .addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.key == "Enter") {
      weather.search();
    }
  });
//Displaying Athens sunrise sunset on page load
weather.fetchWeather("Athens");
```

**I want it to display the normal sunrise-sunset local time for each city without them displaying in Greece's timezone.**

Can anyone help me? I am begginer so I would appreciate if you could elaborate on your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your API response you will receive a `timezone` attribute which is in seconds (positive/negative). You can extract that from there. I converted the UNIX timestamp to UTC and added the `timezone`.

Here is sunrise time for Tirana Albania

```js
let timezone = 3600;
let sunrise = 1642226661;

let x = moment.utc(sunrise,'X').add(timezone,'seconds').format('HH:mm a');

console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use library like moment.js?. can we use simple Date object to do this?

Comment: @FaizanFarooq it is possible of course. I provided momentjs code since OP has used moment in his code

Comment: thanks, So alll i need is to add timezone difference to uct time and i'm ok?

Comment: @FaizanFarooq yeah something like `new Date((timezone+sunrise)*1000).toUTCString()` but you may have do some formatting which is not directly available in vanilla Date

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by getting timezone offset of the browser in seconds and adding it to the timestamp and the timezone offset of the timestamp location to get the time in the timezone of the location instead of the browser timezone.

```
function readTimeStamp(unixTimestamp: number, timezoneOffset: number) {
    const clientOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
    const offsetTimestamp = (unixTimestamp + (clientOffset * 60) + timezoneOffset)
    var date = new Date(offsetTimestamp * 1000);

    return date.toLocaleTimeString();
  }
```